# How to place a button over the center of another button in Android

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

I have two image buttons, button1 and button2. For button1, I am setting a bigger image and for button2 I am setting a small image. I have to place button2 exactly at the center of button1. How do I achieve this?

I am using relative layout and I have to do this changes in an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file. I need to receive click events also separately for both the buttons.

I have tried the below code, but I am not receiving separate click events.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/mainscreen"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adView"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:src="@drawable/drum"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:focusable="false" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/drum1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/drum2"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:src="@drawable/drum"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image5"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/drum1"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image4"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image6"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/drum2"
        android:background="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image4"
        android:focusable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: paste your xml file will make changes

Comment: whare is your ralative layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current layout, you will need to nest the items.  but since you're only interested in the image part of the imagebutton, you can just use a FrameLayout for what you're currently calling "button1" like in my example (adapt to your circumstances):

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/button1"
  ...
  android:background="@drawable/image1"
  >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/image2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this.I am using three buttons and trying to place one on top of other.Can we achieve this using frame layout?

Comment: Sure.... a button is just a view like anything else.  If you just want something to be clickable, you don't have to make it a button.  FrameLayout renders each thing inside it on top of the others - so if your biggest Image is the frameLayout, then you have one smaller in the exact center, you could still have yet another in the center of both.  They're drawn in the order that they're put in the FrameLayout, so the first one will be on bottom

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use FrameLayout to contains both buttons

Answer (score 0):

For the second image, set the attribute `aligncenterinparent = true`.

Comment: buttons aren't viewgroups - the second button isn't inside the other one

Comment: how do you know the 1st button takes the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use a frame layout. Put button1 as fill parent and button 2 as wrap content with layout_gravity="center" . Look at the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_frame" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pic_2" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not only two buttons I am using almost six buttons in my layout, so if I use match_parent for imageButton1 it may create problem.How to take care all six buttons?

Comment: define a size for the framelayout for the height attribute in dips. This will keep things easy and Image button 1 would only fill the parent framelayout.